# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 127: unexpected end of data

Tags: python

I have a problem decoding some characters, the error is like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 127: unexpected end of data
```

Below is my code, 'response' variable is JSON

```
response = requests.post('LINK-TO-API', headers=headers, data=data)
result = ""
for i in response:
    result += i.decode('utf-8')
```

whats wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you dump the `JSON` to a file before decoding and post it. You might see problem as well.

Comment: We can't see what the remote sent you and whether or not it was supposed to be in UTF-8 at all. You should probably [edit] your question to provide more details. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: as @kabanus said, you should dump it to json first, otherwise you won't have a clear idea what the server sends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xD0` (`0b11010000`) is one of many bytes that indicate the start of a multi-byte sequence in UTF-8. The number of 1s before the first 0 indicate the length of the sequence*. The bits after the first 0 are part of the encoding of the code point.

Basically, the iterator of the response has cut a two byte encoding in half. You should read the entire contents of the response before trying to decode it. eg.

```
bytes_ = b''
for chunk in response:
    bytes_ += chunk
result = bytes_.decode('utf8')
```

* bytes starting `10` indicate a continuation byte in a multi-byte sequence rather than a 1-byte encoding.

Comment: You are assuming that the result is UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: True, the text could be encoded using a different encoding. However, it's not a terrible assumption either, given the ubiquity of UTF-8 and streetCoder3127917 explicitly decoding the bytes as such. But then the problem occurred at index 127, which would seem like an unnaturally short packet, and so suggests it really was the end of the data.